# Explicit Title for toctree in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

I am trying to explicitly set the title of an element in my `toctree`.  The documentation says it should be this:

```
.. toctree::

    All about strings <string>
```

But it just prints the title of what's in the string.rst document, and not "All about strings".

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Lukas Graf's answer, sphinx 1.1.2 has your exact problem. I tried it out with 1.1.3: no problems. (On python 2.7, osx).

I don't see anything specific in [Sphinx' 1.1.3 changelog](http://sphinx-doc.org/changes.html#release-1-1-3-mar-10-2012), though there is a mention of "restoring compatibility with docutils trunk". This suggests that another docutils version *could* help you. I'm using version `0.9`.

So: sphinx `1.1.3` and docutils `0.9`, could you try those versions?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this with Sphinx 1.1.2. This seems to be a bug, possibly a regression of [issue #86](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/86). This issue was apparently fixed in [0.5.2](http://sphinx-doc.org/changes.html#release-0-5-2-mar-24-2009), but seems to have found its way back in.